# MS Access: How do make Access search for a filename based on what a user selected in a combo box?

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax, import, path

I know how to make Access import a spreadsheet by stating its location and filename, but in the same folder I have 3 similar files. I want the user to be able to import the one they want by selecting a value in a combobox.

For example, if the user selects "A" from the combobox, then Access should look for the spreadsheet called "Spreadsheet_A". What is the syntax to accomplish this?

**What I've tried:**

I tried making a macro and using the ImportExportSpreadsheet action. I tried specifying the file name as `J:\blah\Spreadsheet_[Combo353]` and also `J:\blah\Spreadsheet_+[Combo353]` and even `J:\blah\Spreadsheet_+"[Combo353]`" but they all return the same error:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'J:\blah\Spreadsheet_[Combo353].xlsx. Make sure the object exists.....

I'm positive that the path is correct, I just need to know the syntax of how to make it use the value in the combo box. If not possible, I'm happy with a VBA solution as well.

---

**Solution was a two-part thing: write the correct syntax (see answer below) and also unset the `strpath` variable**

Comment: Check your combo box. Is the name of the spreadsheet appearing in drop down the bound column or is a hidden ID the bound column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right:

```
"J:\blah\Spreadsheet_" & [Forms]![MyFormName]![Combo353].Value & ".xls"
```

Assuming the code is running from the form containing the combobox.

The path is static, so that is considered a string. Strings are held in double-quotes. Then we want to add the combo value to the end of that string. When you add a string to a string, you perform "Concatenation," which requires the ampersand to show that the two strings should be added together. Since the combobox reference is identifying the control whose value we want to drop into the string, that is left out of the quotations so Access evaluates the value instead of the control name itself.

Comment: The code is running from a button I made on the same form as the combo box.

Comment: I think he uses makro not `vba` so it should be `= "J:\blah\Spreadsheet_" & [Forms]![myForm]![Combo353].Value`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat I forgot to add the file extension. I have edited my answer. If you get the same error, post the control source of your combobox and the code opening the file.

Comment: @BitAccesser yes, I am trying this in a macro. I listed VBA in case this is *impossible* with a macro (in order to keep things simple!)

Comment: Same error @ChristopherD. What do you mean by the control source and the code opening the file? For the combo box I'm using the On Click event to run an Embedded Macro and then in the screen where one can create a macro I'm using the ImportExportSpreadsheet action.

Comment: @what Did my comment work for you , if not show the error message!

Comment: @BitAccesser it did not work. I get the same error message for all different combinations suggested so far (see the error in the question). It can't seem to "find the object". I made sure to copy the path directly from the Windows File Explorer and also copy the first part of the file name so that there is no way I could make a typo.

Comment: `The Microsoft database engine could not find the object 'J:\blah\"J:\blah\Spreadsheet_" & [Forms]![MainForm]![Combo353].Value & ".xlsx"'. Make sure the object exists....`

Comment: That's really weird - it's recognizing the file path twice even though in my macro I certainly don't write it twice...

Comment: @what Please post your macro and the control source of your combo box. The control source is in the properties of your combo box. It should be a SQL statement. Edit your question to include those two things.

Comment: @what you missed the `=` at start!

Comment: @ChristopherD. strange but the control source for the combo box is blank, yet I still get the 4 values I want.... editing the question in a bit, need to switch locations/computers.

Comment: I figured out what was causing that error. The problem was that while I was testing this out, I used some VBA code I found online to set the strPath to the file location. So I just cleared the variable using `Set strPath = Nothing`. But I'm getting another error now - `Field 'F1' doesn't exist in the destination table 'table_A.'`

Comment: My table has 2 fields: an autonumber `ID` field and an `item` field. I need to clear the contents of the table before importing, then only import the 1 column in the spreadsheet to the `item` column in the table. Any thoughts?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat I can't help you there since I don't know the macro importing the table. Considering you are getting an error on a new line, I suggest closing this question and asking another question to address your new issue.